# MongoDB connection ends prematurely

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test",function(err,db){
    if(err) throw err;
    var query = {};
    var projection = {State : 1,Temperature : 1,_id : 1};
    var options = {
        sort : [["State","asc"],["Temperature","desc"]]
    };
    var state = "";
    var temp = 0;
    db.collection("weather").find(query,projection,options).each(function(err,doc){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(doc){
            // Check if we have found a new state
            if(state !== doc.State){
                state = doc.State;
                doc["month_high"] = true;
                db.collection("weather").save(doc,function(err,saved){
                    if(err) throw err;
                });
            }
        }else{
            return db.close();
        }
    });
});
```

This is my code where I have to update certain documents that meet a criteria. Instead of storing all the documents that need to be updated, and then updating them later, I am updating them as they come.

However, I get a `MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed`. I know this is because I am trying to use a connection that has already been closed.

How do I properly sequence the closing of the database and updating of the documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your last `db.save()` is still being processed when you call `db.close()`

Check if you are processing the last item and then call `db.close()` in your `db.save()` callback.

Comment: "Check if you are processing the last item". There is no way to know if this is the last item unless I store it in an array and then check the index to see if I am processing the last item. Is there no other way? :)

Comment: "check the index to see if I am processing the last item." pretty much - I would not know anything better right now. Worth a try to see if your error goes away.